# Issue in Match Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am creating a node using the particular query :-

> create (n:HMP_QUERY_NODE{attributeTypes:
>   '"attrMap":{}',dependentId:85,isSingle:false,
>        nodeCategory: "MDFConcept",
>       queryDesc:" MATCH(mdf:MDFConcept)-[:_properties]->(auditnode)-->(spoke)
>       where spoke.identifier='MDF.Alternate' AND spoke.status ='Confirmed' AND spoke.start_date <= timestamp() <= spoke.end_date
>       with distinct mdf
>       OPTIONAL MATCH (mdf)<-[r]-()
>       where NOT(type(r) IN ['ConceptHasChild','hasInstance']) AND r.status = 'Confirmed' AND r.start_date <= timestamp() <= r.end_date
>       with mdf,count(r) as relCount where relCount=0
>       return mdf.elementLabel, mdf._type, relCount",
>       queryId:123,queryLabel:" MDF – AlternateNodes Without Relationship",queryName:" MDF - General Reports ", 
>       queryOptionId:1 ,queryOptions:"" ,status:"D"}) RETURN n

I am able to create the query but still its giving error in UI.
[image: Error In Neo4j Server]

Next, I tried to get this particular node through this query :

> MATCH (node:HMP_QUERY_NODE) WHERE node.status = 'D'  AND   node.queryName =  'MDF - General Reports'   RETURN node.queryLabel,node.dependentId,node.queryId

The result I m getting should have the current node I created from the above query but its not there.

[image: Match stmt resultset]

Now, I am unable to understand whats the issue.
I tried getting the node with other variables also but still no gain.

**Neo4j Browser version: 3.0.11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put spaces in your create query: queryName:" MDF - General Reports ".
I would recommend to use the function: trim() in your cypher and you will see the result.

```
MATCH (node:HMP_QUERY_NODE) WHERE node.status = 'D' AND trim(node.queryName) = 'MDF - General Reports' RETURN node.queryLabel,node.dependentId,node.queryId
```

Result:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════╤══════════════╤═════════════════════════╕
│"node.queryLabel"                           │"node.dependentId"│"node.queryId"│"node.queryName"         │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│" MDF – AlternateNodes Without Relationship"│85                │123           │" MDF - General Reports "│
└────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```